# Live markers from list of coordinates?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

### Prerequisites

I have created a styled map using the Google Maps API. The full HTML is here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Live Markers</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   }
   #map {
    height: 100%;
   }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
  function initMap() {
   var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType([
    {
     "featureType": "all",
     "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
     "stylers": [
      {
       "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      {
       "visibility": "off"
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "featureType": "all",
     "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
     "stylers": [
      {
       "visibility": "off"
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "featureType": "administrative",
     "elementType": "geometry",
     "stylers": [
      {
       "visibility": "on"
      },
      {
       "color": "#333739"
      },
      {
       "weight": 0.8
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "featureType": "landscape",
     "elementType": "geometry",
     "stylers": [
      {
       "color": "#2ecc71"
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "featureType": "poi",
     "elementType": "all",
     "stylers": [
      {
       "color": "#2ecc71"
      },
      {
       "lightness": -7
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "featureType": "poi.park",
     "elementType": "all",
     "stylers": [
      {
       "color": "#2ecc71"
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "featureType": "road",
     "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
     "stylers": [
      {
       "color": "#333739"
      },
      {
       "weight": 0.3
      },
      {
       "lightness": 10
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "featureType": "road.highway",
     "elementType": "geometry",
     "stylers": [
      {
       "color": "#2ecc71"
      },
      {
       "lightness": -28
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "featureType": "road.arterial",
     "elementType": "geometry",
     "stylers": [
      {
       "color": "#2ecc71"
      },
      {
       "visibility": "on"
      },
      {
       "lightness": -15
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "featureType": "road.local",
     "elementType": "geometry",
     "stylers": [
      {
       "color": "#2ecc71"
      },
      {
       "lightness": -18
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "featureType": "transit",
     "elementType": "geometry",
     "stylers": [
      {
       "color": "#2ecc71"
      },
      {
       "lightness": -34
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "featureType": "water",
     "elementType": "geometry",
     "stylers": [
      {
       "color": "#333739"
      }
     ]
    }
   ], {
    name: 'Custom Style'
   });

   var customMapTypeId = 'custom_style';
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: {lat: 40.674, lng: -73.946},  // Brooklyn.
    disableDefaultUI: true
   });

   map.mapTypes.set(customMapTypeId, customMapType);
   map.setMapTypeId(customMapTypeId);
  }

  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

### Goal

I want to display a live "marker" on this map. A PHP script on the server responds to any request with a plain-text list of coordinates. There may be one or more coordinates in this response. Duplicates are possible. An example would be:

```
52.374 4.89
37.77 -122.394
55.75 37.617
37.77 -122.394
```

A request to that PHP script must be made every 5 seconds. If the response is different from the last one, then all *unique* coordinates should appear as "markers" on the map.

But they should not be static. What I have in mind is some kind of "drop" effect, where a new marker is an animated, solid color, circle that expands and then fades out. Duplicates should be ignored (in one request).

If the response only contains one pair of coordinates, only one marker must be animated. If there are more, all positions must be animated at the same time. That means, that no matter how much markers there are, the time it takes for all of the animations to complete is constant.

### Question

How would I implement this? I want to use JS and `XMLHttpRequest` to make the request to the PHP script and fetch the string. Is it even possible to do this with JS and the GMaps API? If so, how?

Also: How would I implement the animation itself?

Comment: If you downvote *and* closevote, please leave a comment regarding possible improvements.

Comment: the reason you're getting downvoted is because you're basically asking someone to build an application for you.

Comment: I'm trying to get this... so you basically want to dynamically add new markers on the fly based on what you're getting from the server, and not duplicate any markers either in the same response or from past responses?

Comment: This is not a question, this is a programming delegation.

Answer (score 0):

Implement using a timer `setInterval(ajaxRequestFunction, 5000)`

Then inside the ajaxRequestFunction create a success handler that will update your googlemap with the markers.  You will (probably?) want to clear the markers first and then add each one in the array by first creating a marker object each time and then adding it to the map.

The [googlemaps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference) has all of that functionality available for you in the client.